# I want to show customer custom filed value in Sales -> Order -> view page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

I used magento extension to add custom field in register page. After creation I am trying to show this value in **Sales** -> **Order** -> view page Under "**ACCOUNT INFORMATION**" section by making changes in **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml** files.

I try with same code as currently present in there, like to show name and email :-

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerName()) ?>

<?php echo $_order->getCustomerEmail() ?>
```

Similarly I use the below code for my custom field (dp_account_no)

```
<?php echo $_order->getCustomerDpAccountNo() ?>
```

I also checked other default fields the will work fine like

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerLastname()) ?>
```

to show last name.

Please suggest me what wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: No friend. I am still looking on this issue.